How can I force a ext4 filesystem as dirty, to force fsck?
I am testing some software which mounts disks from a external storage on a Linux host based on some request.
As part of this, there is a feature that if the mount fails due to a filesystem error it will run fsck.
In order to test this functionality, I need to mark something in an ext4 filesystem that will result in mount failure but be fixable by fsck.

I have tried marking the dirty bit via debugfs - it does not result in a mount failure.
I have tried changing the magic number to some random value - that is not a option as we need the magic number (limitation in tool).
I tried setting some groups descriptor bitmap or blocks to 0 - that did not work either.
Is there any consistent way this can be achieved?

Why not just run fsck unconditionally before mounting?  If the filesystem is clean, it will exit immediately with no action.

@TobySpeight - i m trying to test the existing workflow that this software does - it only does fsck on filesystems that have failed to mount.
Making fsck run on every mount does not test the existing software functionality

Looking at the source code, I think you want to force the EFSCORRUPTED error.
It looks to me that the most promising line is this one:
    if (!S_ISDIR(root->i_mode) || !root->i_blocks || !root->i_size) {
            ext4_msg(sb, KERN_ERR, "corrupt root inode, run e2fsck");
            iput(root);
            err = -EFSCORRUPTED;
            goto failed_mount4;
    }

That checks that the root directory is as expected. The safest parameter to change would be the size, that I think can be reconstructed from the inode list. You can set the size of the root diretory to 0 with this command:
$ printf '\n\n\n0' | debugfs -w fs_image -R 'modify_inode /'

And if you wish you can force fsck by setting the dirty bit (you know this one, but for completion):
$ debugfs -w fs_image -R 'dirty'

Then, if I try to mount this I get this error:
corrupt root inode, run e2fsck

After a fsck it looks like the size of the root diretory is properly restored. No guarantees though, backup your data first, just in case.

this seems to do the trick!. Thanks @rodrigo
